# custom menu on google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Need expert help, can we run function directly from the menu, instead of Sub-menu, it fails double clicking.
and I would want to close the dialog box after the download start, and can we delete the sheet after we download it ? :

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().deleteSheet(.getSheetId(sID));

function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Download')
      .addItem('Download', 'Download')
      .addToUi();
}           
function Download() {           
  var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  var sID = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetId();            
  var URL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+ssID+'/export?format=pdf&gid='+sID;

  var htmlOutput = HtmlService          
                  .createHtmlOutput('<a href="'+URL+'">Click to download</a>')
                  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
                  .setWidth(160)
                  .setHeight(60);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Download');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the very top level menu, then the answer would be no.

You can delete a sheet but you will have to put a spreadsheet into the trash first. Although I think it's possible for GSuite Admins to get file delete authorization. I don't know I never bothered with it.

You can close the dialog box with `google.script.host.close()` [Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/host)

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank" onClick="google.script.host.close();">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: how do I set this `google.script.host.close()` into my script

I want the dialog box to close after we click the download link and I know for deleting sheet is `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().deleteSheet(.getSheetId(sID));`
also how do i insert this line into my script file

Comment: How about this: `<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank" onClick="google.script.host.close();">Click Me</a>`